# Programmatically control width of sidePanel in Chrome Extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Im making a Chrome Extension using the sidePanel API: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/sidePanel/

Is there a way set the width of the side panel programatically? Id like to increase the width of the panel when a button within the extension is clicked.

Comment: Not a pro, but could you not do it with the content script? Selecting the element by some selector and assigning width to it?

Comment: @AidHadzic the side panel is its on context and not part of the page in that way.

Comment: No, there's no way, it's a part of the built-in UI and Chrome never allows extensions to control it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The side panel API doesn't support it at the moment. But this issue is extensively discussed on the [mailing list](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/g/chromium-extensions/c/cJmdMLmpbjg/m/imr8dLY8AQAJ?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer).